# Error trying to run spring application:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinitionCustomizer

Tags: spring

I'm having an error when i try to run my spring project on eclipse.

The error is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinitionCustomizer
at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.registerBean(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:145) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.register(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:135) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:158) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:135) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:127) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.load(SpringApplication.java:701) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:390) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:9) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionCustomizer
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
... 11 common frames omitted
```

I have a basic controller with some mappings, one entity with no annotations and some auxiliar classes.

Do you have any ideas? I searched for solution and i found the bean dependency but it's not working..
thanks

Comment: Try to add relevant part of your code to get more context.

Comment: @sGambolati I think the problem is not on the code.. I think the error is on some missing dependency... I'm just starting a project and there's no complex things until now. thanks

Comment: Is this a maven project ?

Comment: Spring web project

Comment: What spring version are you using ? The latest ?  you may have a conflict of versions. by the way I recommend using maven or gradle

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven, make sure you have the spring-context dependency added to your `pom.xml`

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

**5.0.6.RELEASE** is the latest release, but you can substitute the version of spring you're using there